# VSCODE missing run tasks after update

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just updates VSCODE to v1.67.2.  The Terminal | run tasks command ( F9 ) vanished!

How do I get it back?

-or-

How do I revert to the previous version?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved when I restarted VSCODE